# disable ng-click on a non-button element

Tags: angularjs

I am using `<p>` tags to display a set of answer choices. Each choice is selectable, which sets a class and runs some function when clicked.

I want to disable any `ng-click` action once an answer has been selected and `$scope.question_checked === true`. I tried following the format for disabling buttons, but this doesn't work the same with non button elements.

```
            <p
               ng-repeat="c in choices track by ($index+1)"
               ng-click="question_checked || c.selected = !c.selected; makeSelection($index+1, this)"
               class="choice"
               ng-class="{'selected': c.selected==true}"
               ng-disabled="question_checked">

                {{letters[$index]}}) {{c.choice}}

            </p>
```

How can I disable the `ng-click` on, for example, a `p` element?

How it is currently, I get the error:

> Error: [$parse:lval] Trying to assing a value to a non l-value

This is when I have `c.selected = !c.selected;` in `ng-click` along with the other function.

Comment: Why not use an anchor tag as opposed to a paragraph tag?  You can style it any way you want...

Comment: @Growler, So, for example, if you have 5 options for a question, and if user select any one of the option then all other options need to go disabled state. right?

Answer (score 0):

```
<p ng-repeat="c in choices track by ($index+1)"
   ng-init="question_checked = false"
   ng-click="(!question_checked ? makeSelection($index+1, this) : return); question_checked = true"
   class="choice"
   ng-class="{'selected': c.selected==true}">

       {{letters[$index]}}) {{c.choice}}

</p>
```

initiate a `ng-repeat` child scope variable to `false` as `ng-init="question_checked = false"`

if `question_checked == false` then `makeSelection()` calls if not equals then nothing happens just a `return` after that `question_checked` assign to true as `question_checked = true`

```
ng-click="(!question_checked ? makeSelection($index+1, this) : return); question_checked = true"
```

we don't need `ng-disabled` here.

Comment: you removed `c.selected = !c.selected;`, this is how I set the `ng-class` for the `p` tag

Comment: remove `ng-init` and then replace all the `question_checked ` with `c.selected` i cant see any important of `question_checked `.